# Why is this wordpress page non-responsive?

Tags: wordpress, css, mobile, contact-form

The [site](http://jadeluxurycondos.com/jadeluxurycondos-new/contact/) I am referring to isn't showing up properly on the mobile side.

Here is a look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kn98P/) `<div id="contactWrapper">`.  In regards to the actual contact form, the one you will see in JSFiddle will show the short-code.  Please refer to the site to see the actual contact form 7 in which I am referring to.

The contact page shows excellent on the desktop version, but the mobile side isn't functioning properly in a responsive format.

I am seeking some insight to help me solve this problem.  If you have a few minutes to take a look at the problem and give your input, that would be appreciative.

Comment: Tested the website with my good ol' Sony Xperia, looks fine, the contact form is working, what is **exactly** the problem?

Comment: @bodi0 -  the form needs to move to the left a bit, it's not centered, but only on mobile side

Answer (score 0):

your problem  `#contact2` and `#contact1` have pixel size:

```
# contact1 {
display: table-cell; 
width: 380px; 
float: left; 
margin-top: 20px; 
} 

# contact2 {
display: table-cell; 
width: 670px; 
float: left; 
}
```

replace it by:

```
# contact1 {
display: table-cell; 
width: 30%; 
float: left; 
margin-top: 20px; 
} 

# contact2 {
display: table-cell; 
width: 70%; 
float: left; 
}
```

Comment: This didn't work.  the form is there, it actually needs to move to the left, but on on mobile side.